# What can you use voice sound for?

Tags: acoustics

Moreover, how can you make your voice productive? for example, using it to light an LED, charge a battery, purificating water, growing plants in a more efficient way. I want to do a project that involves using my singing voice to achieve something.

Comment: was the question "How much power has a human voice?" `A: xxx milli watts which is the power of n red LED`

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever spoken into a microphone you've had the energy carried by your voice converted to electrical power. That electrical power could be used for anything you want, e.g. run an electric motor (though it would have to be a very small motor as you'll see below).

But ...

The power carried by a human voice is exceedingly small. If you shout as loudly as you possibly can, the [power at 1m is around 75dB](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/voice-level-d_938.html). The [power in decibels is given by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_power):

$$ L = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{P}{P_0} \right) $$

where $P$ is the power per square metre and $P_0$ is a reference level of $10^{-12}$ W/m$^2$. Using this equation we can calculate the power in a loud shout, and it works out to be about $0.5$ mW/m$^2$, and that's shouting as loudly as you possibly can **and** shouting continuously.

So even if you could convert the energy in your voice to useful power with 100% efficiency there's just not enough power to be worth the trouble.